# First test of a Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I downloaded the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone and I wrote a simple application to make a first test of the emulator. In this application I have only a button with the property Content binded to a string called ButtonText and with the property Background binded to a SolidColorBrush named FillColor. I handled the Click event with this code:

```
    void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (toggle == true)
        {
            ButtonText = "Blue";
            FillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonText = "Red";
            FillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. While the Content of the Button changes each time the button is pressed, I cannot say the same for the Background which remains at the same color.
Could you tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

I also post the XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="MyButton" Width="300" Height="300"
                Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText}" 
                Background="{Binding Path=FillColor}" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems            

button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

doesn't work either, so not a binding issue.

May be worth posting this on Connect if an explanation isn't forthcoming.. there is a wp7 category under VS.

Comment: Setting fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); works to initialize the background. It doesn't work only when that property is changed.

Comment: are you setting the dataContext of the page?

Comment: @Chris: yes I do. In fact, the Button's Content property changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the use of "new" in the line:

FillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

Using the "new" operation breaks the data binding that was previously set up.  Try using the following instead:

FillColor.Color = Colors.Blue;

Replace both the changes to Blue and to Red and that should do the trick.

HTH!
Chris

Comment: Thank you for your answer. FillColor's type is not Color, but SolidColorBrush. If I convert it to Color it didn't work because Background's type is not Color.
Moreover, I don't agree with you when you say that the "new" operation breaks the data binding, in fact the same solutions works perfectly in a silverlight web site.

Comment: If you notice in my response, I suggested you change the value of FillColor's Color property, not the FillColor property itself. In my recreation of your issue that fixed the basic problem.  I have experienced this same issue with ObservableCollection where newing up an instance inside your code after databinding it will in fact break the binding.  I can provide complete code samples to show this in more detail if you're interested...

Comment: Thank you again Chris. I'm interested to your code sample. You can find my e-mail in my profile. I'll be glad of your help if you send me the code samples.